# Issue Keystore Elasticsearch 8.X on docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm encountering a problem while trying to run a small version of Elasticsearch 8.X without security for testing purposes on Docker. The command I'm using is:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" elastic/elasticsearch:8.11.3
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: unable to create temporary keystore at [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.keystore.tmp], write permissions required for [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config] or run [elasticsearch-keystore upgrade], with exit code 78
```

I've tried to mount the requested volume with the correct permissions without success. It's worth mentioning that the same Docker command works perfectly with Elasticsearch 7.X, so I'm a bit confused about what's causing this issue.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and if so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce that. It works for me. Do you have any leftovers from a previous start? Also, the error prevents the container from starting or is just logged? Though I don't even have that in the log (`docker logs <id> | grep -i "error"`).

Comment: it prevents to start. Let me see if i can clean any leftovers

Comment: if i run `docker system prune -a`, it works indeed...